# jar: Package org.apache.catalina.ssi missing from ModulePackages class file attribute

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I changed my tomcat version 9 to 8 but when I wrote `jar uf ../catalina.jar org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties` it gave me the following error

> jar: Package org.apache.catalina.ssi missing from ModulePackages class
> file attribute

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I have got that message in a simple Maven project from maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0. Which give a hint, that Tomcat is not the very source. No clue where comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Upgraded from apache 9.0.16 to 9.0.41, wanted to remove server version/infos, edited ServerInfo.properties, and when time came to
jar uf ../catalina.jar org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
got the same error than you.

I think I found the why :
I opened catalina.jar both on 9.0.16 and 9.0.41, and lo and behold : there is no ssi in org/apache/catalina/ for 9.0.41
Yet the MANIFEST.MF still includes it, as well as the module-info.class

From reading Tomcat changelog, it looks like this happened with tomcat 9.0.30 :
*Moved server-side include (SSI) module into a separate JAR library. (schultz)*
(looking in the lib directory, it seems like it is catalina-ssi.jar now)

Not sure how clean this is, but I went around the problem by opening catalina.jar with 7zip, modify the ServerInfo.properties from there, saved, restarted Tomcat, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That is a really weird issue I'm facing myself right know, excluding

```
org.apache.catalina.ssi from the module-info.class
```

using [ModiTect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) helped, hope it won't crash in a long run...