# Docker Tomcat 9.0.45 Stateless Container Hardening - Change ServerInfo.properties

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, containers, tomcat9

As one of the hardening tasks defined for Tomcat, I'm supposed to change the output of `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/version.sh` to output bogus values.

This seemed pretty straight-forward from what I could find.  All of the articles essentially pointed towards:  extract ServerInfo.properties from catalina.jar, modify it, recommit it, and restart Tomcat.

In the stateless container world though, I have to extract it, modify it, recommit it, START tomcat.  If I restart the container after tomcat is started, the container dies.  Here are the steps I tried in my container entrypoint shell script:

```
jar -xf /opt/tomcat/lib/catalina.jar org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
sed -i 's@server.info=.*@server.info=Server@' /opt/tomcat/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
sed -i 's@server.number=.*@server.info=0.0@' /opt/tomcat/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
jar -uf /opt/tomcat/lib/catalina.jar org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
```

However, in 9.0.45, the recommit back to catalina.jar throws an error:

```
jar: Package org.apache.catalina.ssi missing from ModulePackages class file attribute
```

Investigating this, I found this article:  [jar: Package org.apache.catalina.ssi missing from ModulePackages class file attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870630/jar-package-org-apache-catalina-ssi-missing-from-modulepackages-class-file-attr)

...which essentially said it's a bug in newer versions of tomcat and the guy who got around it used 7zip instead of jar.  So I modified my code with the following:

```
mkdir -p /opt/tomcat/test
pushd /opt/tomcat/test
7z x -y /opt/tomcat/lib/catalina.jar:org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
sed -i 's@server.info=.*@server.info=Server@' /opt/tomcat/test/ServerInfo.properties
sed -i 's@server.number=.*@server.info=0.0@' /opt/tomcat/test/ServerInfo.properties
7z u /opt/tomcat/lib/catalina.jar:org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties /opt/tomcat/test/ServerInfo.properties
popd
```

...while this *did* work in-so-far as I can tell (the ServerInfo.properties file in the backup location (test) did successfully get modified and I received a success indicator from 7zip in the container console log output for the recommit), after tomcat starts and I run version.sh, it still reports the actual verison.

To reiterate, these changes are being applied *before* tomcat is ever started so even though all of the documentation says to restart tomcat after-the-change, I'm expecting that I shouldn't have to restart tomcat (again, since this operation kills the container and wipes any interactive container changes (stateless)).

EDIT 1:
In an effort to confirm, after the container is started, I've exec'd into the container to verify that the entrypoint script was successful.  I manually extracted the file out of catalina.jar and verified that the operations did appear to be successful because the interactively-extracted ServerInfo.properties from catalina.jar does reflect the changes (so the process appears to have worked) but running $CATALINA_HOME/bin/version.sh still shows the actual version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another option which is much easier and works just fine.

*Alternatively, the version number can be changed by creating the file CATALINA_BASE/lib/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties with content as follows...*
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-howto.html#web.xml

You don't need to replace anything in `catalina.jar`
Just create this extra config file as follows, that is enough.

```
mkdir -p "${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/org/apache/catalina/util"
echo "server.info=X" > "${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties"

## proceed with tomcat start...
```

---

**Bonus**
Remove server info from HTTP headers in server responses (also check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/840211/set-tomcat-to-production-mode)).

```
## turn off server info and stacktraces on error pages
file="${CATALINA_HOME}"/conf/server.xml
xmlstarlet edit -L \
    --delete "//Connector[starts-with(@protocol, 'HTTP')]/@server" \
    --insert "//Connector[starts-with(@protocol, 'HTTP')]" -t attr -n "server" -v "X" \
    --delete "//Valve[@className='org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve']" \
    --subnode "/Server/Service[@name='Catalina']/Engine[@name='Catalina']/Host[@name='localhost']" -t elem -n "Valve" \
    --insert "/Server/Service[@name='Catalina']/Engine[@name='Catalina']/Host[@name='localhost']/Valve[not(@className)]" -t attr -n "className" -v "org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" \
    --insert "//Valve[@className='org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve']" -t attr -n "showReport" -v "false" \
    --insert "//Valve[@className='org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve']" -t attr -n "showServerInfo" -v "false" \
${file}
```